# Solidity does not refund gas when deleting storage

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I wrote a simple contract to verify that solidity refund gas when deleting storage.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;    
contract Storage {

    bool[] private data = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                           true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                           true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                           true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                           true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true
                           ];

    event Count(uint i);
    function removeRange(bool isDelete) public returns(bool[] memory) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {  
            emit Count(j);
            if(!isDelete) {
                continue;
            }
            delete data[j];
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I added a counter to the methods to perform an operation which cost gas.  Remix returned this in the logs when not deleting:

> gas    151499 gas

> transaction cost   131738 gas

> execution cost 131738 gas

When I do call the function which deletes the storage nothing is refunded an infact my gas price is higher:

> gas   186013 gas
> transaction cost  152150 gas
> execution cost    152150 gas

How can I verify gas refund functionality via solidity contract?

Answer (score 0):

Data in a blockchain ( such as the Ethereum protocol ) can't be erased or modified. In Solidity, the `delete` keyword isn't used to free storage space, it just sets the current variable's value to 0, or false, or its "default value".

So as a matter of fact you'll be using more gas because you're actually sending a new transaction to the blockchain with the new value, and the allocated storage for your variables stays the same.

More info [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#delete).

PD: Just to clarify, as mentioned, in a blockchain you can't delete data nor modify it, that's why when developing with Solidity, when you update a state variable's value, you're actually sending a new transaction to the blockchain telling the blockchain what's the current state of that storage, but that doesn't mean that its previous value is erased, you can always access its last values by checking the transactions related to that storage variable.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean you can't delete data? You can change the state of the data to obtain a refund on gas, and you can kill contracts to refund gas.  I think you're referring to the fact that you can replay previous transactions to figure out what the previous state of a variable is?

Comment: I've searched a bit more about what you mentioned about gas being refunded when deleting a variable or contract, might be related to: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3298. But, i've never experienced any gas refund when deleting variables tho, and since the delete keyword only sets the variable to 0, the call to this instruction only used more gas to change the state. I'll research a bit more about this, if I find something of interest I'll let you know :)

Comment: hmm, I think its related to EIP 150, the refund comes after the call and you can only get refunded 50% of the gas used.  The refund is counts for zeroing out data.  I'm trying to see it in action thou